# Displayin data from data base with condition

Tags: php, mysql, database, conditional-statements

I want to know if there's a resolving of displayin data from the database but with condition;
if the column contains "0" or null don't show the data.
Please I want help because I need it so much!

Comment: We don't have enough information to be able to really help you. Could you please give more details of the query that you want to add a where statement and what the problem with said query is?

Comment: Sounds like you may want a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers are ways of getting this information using sql alone.If you want to use PHP, you can use SQL:

```
$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

and then in PHP, after you've called your query, you can use a

```
foreach($result as $row){
   if ($row['column'] == 0){
         $string = '';
   }else{
     $string = $row['column'];
   }
}
```

The question wasn't detailed enough to know if you wanted a SQL or PHP solution.

Comment: yes I want this, I want the php code if it's possible?

Comment: thanks alot, but is there is a query to select all the colums in one code?

Comment: Can you be clearer with this please? Do you mean `$row` outputs everything or do you mean `SELECT * FROM table`?

Comment: at one sentence  I want this code for all the rows of the table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like?

```
Select *
From tableName
Where columnName is not null
And columnName not = 0
```

Comment: so this is the query but I want this query to be a condition;
Like if this query is tru don't show this as an example

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column<>0 AND column IS NOT NULL
```